# Not able to write the output of testbench to file

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.all;
use std.env.all;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.ALL;
USE STD.TEXTIO.ALL;


ENTITY tb_top IS
END tb_top;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_top IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT c4b
PORT(
     clock : IN  std_logic;
     reset : IN  std_logic;
     count : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;


--Inputs
signal clock : std_logic := '0';
signal reset : std_logic := '0';

--Outputs
signal count : STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";

-- Clock period definitions
constant period : time := 100 ns;

-- Opening the file in write mode
file myfile : TEXT open write_mode is "fileio.txt";

BEGIN
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    uut: c4b PORT MAP (
        clock => clock,
        reset => reset,
        count => count
    );

clock_process :process      --providing clock to the counter
begin
    clock <= '1';
    wait for period/2;
    clock <= '0';
    wait for period/2;
end process;

write_process: process
    variable abd: LINE;
    --variable val1: integer;
    begin
        --val1 := CONV_INTEGER(count);          --saw this in another program. even they converted a std_logic_vector to integer. didn't work!
        loop                                                --tried the infinite loop to check for the value 1111,
            if (count = "1111") then                --so that as soon as count reaches the value 1111, 
                finish (0);                             --it would stop, because i only need to write one entire sequence of the cycle to the file!!
            else
                write (abd, count);                 
                writeline (myfile, abd);            
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;

-- Stimulus process
stim_process: process
begin
    reset <= '0';                                   --because it only works when reset is 0!
    wait for 100 ns;
    if (count = "1111") then                        --the value is written to the text file in a continuous loop,
        finish (0);                                     --which makes he file size go to as much as 1 GB
    end if;                                             --thus to stop it at exactly one cycle!
end process;
END;
```

So, basically what I want to do here is let the counter count up from 0000 too 1111 and then write the entire sequence to a text file. But I only wish to write exactly just one cycle. Hence I've added a loop to check the same. Here in the code above I'm not able to simulate the testbench properly. When I don't include the write_process part of the code, the simulation works perfectly, giving me exactly just one cycle! (Simulator result w/o write_process [picture no 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYDiv.png)). But when I try to use the write_process, not only does it not simulate (Simulator result after adding the write_process) [picture no 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhAWr.png), it also writes UUUU continuously to the file, until I close the ISim, and file size goes to at least a few hundred MBs! Please help!

Comment: Sounds like the testbench is working. It seems like a C4B (whatever that is) outputs `'UUUU'` until it has been reset. Perhaps you only want to output the `count` value once per clock cycle rather than in an infinite loop with no 'wait'. I would add 'wait for rising_edge(clock);` at te end of the loop...

Answer (score 1):

Without the entity/architecture for c4b no one can duplicate your error, it's visible however.

Note that the write process has no sensitivity list nor wait statement and a loop statement that won't exit unless external stimuli is provided - `if  (count = "1111") then` ...

It doesn't seem proper to be using finish in both stim_process and write_process, there's no guarantee of execution order you can lose the last write (if you cure the write process defect).

You have four unused use clauses (numeric_std, std_logic_arith, std_logic_signed, std_logic_textio, with VHDL -2008).

> So, basically what I want to do here is let the counter count up from 0000 too 1111 and then write the entire sequence to a text file.

There's nothing in your code that spools up output until your simulation finishes. Writing a line to file textio.txt occurs for events driving the write process.

Adding a model for c4b:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity c4b is
    port (
        clock:  in  std_logic;
        reset:  in  std_logic;
        count:  out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of c4b is 
begin
    process (clock, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            count <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge (clock) then
            count <= count + 1;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Removing unused use clauses (not strictly necessary):

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
-- USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
-- use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.all;
use std.env.all;
-- USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.ALL;
USE STD.TEXTIO.ALL;
```

Changing the write_process to not endlessly loop:

```
-- write_process: process
--     variable abd: LINE;
--     --variable val1: integer;
--     begin
--         --val1 := CONV_INTEGER(count);          --saw this in another program. even they converted a std_logic_vector to integer. didn't work!
--         loop                                                --tried the infinite loop to check for the value 1111,
--             if (count = "1111") then                --so that as soon as count reaches the value 1111,
--                 finish (0);                             --it would stop, because i only need to write one entire sequence of the cycle to the file!!
--             else
--                 write (abd, count);
--                 writeline (myfile, abd);
--             end if;
--         end loop;
--     end process;

write_process: 
    process
        variable abd: LINE;
    begin
        wait on count;
        wait for 100 ns;
        write (abd, count);                 
        writeline (myfile, abd);   
        if count = "1111" then
            finish (0);
        elsif IS_X(count) then
            report "count contains a metavalue and may not increment";
            finish (-1);
        end if;
    end process;
```

The wait 100 ns; accommodates a reset to insure the counter can increment. It's possible to provide a design description of c4b that doesn't depend on reset. For purposes here, the supplied c4b doesn't do that. The wait 100 ns also provides the sample interval for `count`, which from the component declaration for c4b is free running, driven by `clock` events.

Changing the stim_process to not finish and wait instead:

```
-- -- Stimulus process
-- stim_process: process
-- begin
--     reset <= '0';                                   --because it only works when reset is 0!
--     wait for 100 ns;
--     if (count = "1111") then                        --the value is written to the text file in a continuous loop,
--         finish (0);                                     --which makes he file size go to as much as 1 GB
--     end if;                                             --thus to stop it at exactly one cycle!
-- end process;
-- END;

stim_process: 
    process
    begin
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 100 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
```

Notice this also provides a reset interval seen on the following waveform.

And that gives us:

[image: tb_top.png]

With the contents of textio.txt:

```
more fileio.txt
```

> 0000
>   0001
>   0010
>   0011
>   0100
>   0101
>   0110
>   0111
>   1000
>   1001
>   1010
>   1011
>   1100
>   1101
>   1110
>   1111

It's also possible to end simulation after detecting `count` is "1111" by stopping `clock`, avoiding the use of the finish procedure. Along with a write procedure supplied using the Synopsys package std_logic_texio:

```
procedure WRITE(L:inout LINE; VALUE:in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
```

This would allow the use of VHDL simulators complying to VHDL standard revisions earlier than -2008.